# Optimized way for calculating data from list

Tags: java

```
List<Accumulation> accumulations = repository.getAccumulation();

public class Accumulation implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String mobileNo;
    private String address;
    private int count;

    --
    getter
    setter
}
```

How to get total count from abobe list is easiest way using java.

Currently I am using some basic and common code like below :

```
int totalCount = 0;

for (Accumulation cccumulation : accumulations) {
    totalCount += cccumulation.getCount();
}
```

Comment: `private int double`? That won't compile. Did you mean `private int count`?

Comment: parallel stream i think

Comment: There is nothing wrong with doing it the way your doing it, but if you want an alternate way, use Java 8 Streams: `int totalCount = accumulations.stream().mapToInt(Accumulation::getCount).sum();`

Comment: @Andreas You are correct.

Comment: Define "optimized". Do you mean least amount of code? Easiest to read code? Fastest to execute? Take the least resources?

Comment: @BasilBourque fastest to execute and easiest to read

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty "Fastest to execute" and "easiest to read" are likely contradictory requirements. Your code is fastest to execute, unless list is so *insanely huge* that multi-threading will be faster, even with the overhead of multi-threading. The stream code is perhaps easiest to read, though that is a matter of opinion, but it is slower than a simple `for` loop. If you do need multi-threading, then stream code is definitely easier to read.

Comment: Why don't you use static field?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this is a better way of programming, but I can get it by this

```
class Entity extends ArrayList<Entity>{

    public static int totalCount;
    public static int totalListCount;

    private String mobileNo;
    private String address;
    private int count;
    public String getMobileNo() {
        return mobileNo;
    }
    public void setMobileNo(String mobileNo) {
        this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
        totalCount += count;
    }
    public Entity(String mobileNo, String address, int count) {
        super();
        this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
        this.address = address;
        this.count = count;
        totalCount += count;
    }
    public Entity() {
        super();
    }
    public boolean add(Entity entity) {

        totalListCount += entity.getCount();
        return super.add(entity);       
    }
}

public class CountEntityInList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Entity e1 = new Entity("9999999999", "aaa", 10);
        Entity e2 = new Entity("9999999999", "aaa", 10);
        Entity e3 = new Entity("9999999999", "aaa", 10);
        Entity e4 = new Entity("9999999999", "aaa", 10);
        Entity e5 = new Entity("9999999999", "aaa", 10);
        List<Entity> list = new Entity();
        list.add(e1);
        list.add(e2);
        list.add(e3);
        list.add(e4);
        list.add(e5);
        System.out.println(Entity.totalCount);

        Entity e6 = new Entity();
        e6.setCount(20);
        Entity e7 = new Entity();
        e7.setCount(20);
        Entity e8 = new Entity();
        e8.setCount(20);
        Entity e9 = new Entity();
        e9.setCount(20);
        Entity e10 = new Entity();
        e10.setCount(20);
        System.out.println(Entity.totalCount);

        System.out.println(Entity.totalListCount);
    }
}
```